# IF not working in SELECT

Tags: sql, if-statement, conditional-statements, netezza

im trying to rewrite a procedure and specific query gives trouble. In Sybase this type of condition in query would work but in NETEZZA it displays this error:

> > expected ',' after the IF

I also cant find any examples with netezza conditioning inside query. What would be an alternative ?

```
DECLARE static_date DATE;
...
INSERT INTO test(col1, col2)
SELECT tbl1.colx, (IF tbl2.dateCol< static_date THEN 1 ELSE 2 END IF) as col2
FROM tbl1, tbl2;
```

Comment: and what are these ERRORS? Perhaps it prefers a CASE statement

Comment: It said that it expected ',' after the IF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try case expression:

```
INSERT INTO test(col1, col2)
SELECT tbl1.colx,
       CASE WHEN tbl2.dateCol<static_date then 1 else 2 end as col2
FROM tbl1, tbl2;
```

BTW, try to avoid using implicit join syntax, use the proper join syntax like this:

```
INSERT INTO test(col1, col2)
SELECT tbl1.colx,
       CASE WHEN tbl2.dateCol<static_date then 1 else 2 end as col2
FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON(tbl1.CommonCol = tbl2.CommonCol)
```

And lastly.. you are missing a join condition in your query.. see my ON condition.

Comment: Thanks the CASE WHEN worked, completely forgot about it. About the rest youre right, I was using a short example.